# Webpack reactjs syntax error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I've searched all around and tried all possible solutions but have had no luck fixing this error. I'm guessing the bug is somewhat related to my webpack.config.js/ transforming the reactjs file? I use express serverside and reactjs/jade clientside

When I run webpack I get this error

```
    ERROR in ./src/js/components/header.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/src/js/components/header.jsx: Unexpected token (46:39)
  44 |      return (
  45 |          <div className="col-lg-12">
> 46 |              <li className='pull-left'><Link to "app">Home</Link></a></li>
     |                            ^
  47 |              <li className="pull-left"><a onClick={this.handleClick}>Notifications</a></li>
  48 |              <li className="pull-left"><a onClick={this.handleClick}>Find friends</a></li>
  49 |              <input id="site-search" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.setState.typed} placeholder="search..." aria-label="..." className="col-lg-2 pull-right"/>
    at Parser.pp.raise (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/location.js:22:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/util.js:91:8)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseIdentifier (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:214:10)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseNamespacedName (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:225:19)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseAttribute (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:307:20)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseOpeningElementAt (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:319:31)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:341:29)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:354:30)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElementAt (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:354:30)
    at Parser.pp.jsxParseElement (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:390:15)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:402:21)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:265:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:245:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:176:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:158:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:121:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:583:26)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:1000:26)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:1000:26)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:1000:26)
    at Parser.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/flow.js:1000:26)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:469:19)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
    at Parser.<anonymous> (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/plugins/jsx/index.js:404:22)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:265:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:245:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/home/hakeem/Documents/webapp/app/node_modules/babylon/lib/parser/expression.js:176:19)
 @ ./src/js/main.jsx 17:13-47
```

webpack.config.js

```
var LiveReloadPlugin = require('webpack-livereload-plugin');
   var path = require('path');
   var webpack = require('webpack');

    module.exports={
        //Entry point/Location of the main jsx file to be transformed to JS
        entry: "./src/js/main.jsx",
    //Location where the compiled JS code will be saved
    output: {
        //Location where the output file is to be saved
        path: './build',
        //Name of the output file
        filename: "bundle.js"
    },
    //Modules
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {presets:[ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-0' ]}
            },
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new LiveReloadPlugin()
    ],

    //Resolves using extensions and absolute path
    resolve:
        extensions = ['', '.js']
};
```

main.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

//Leftbar
var Leftbar = require('./components/leftbar');

//Header
var Header = require('./components/header');

//Sidebar
var Leftbar = require('./components/leftbar');

//Posts
var Posts = require('./components/posts');

//Rightbar
var Rightbar = require('./components/rightbar');
var App = React.createClass({
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <Leftbar />
                <aside id="maincontent" className="col-lg-10">
                    <Header />
                    <main>
                      <div id="main-container" className="col-lg-10 row grid">
                        <h3 id="page-title">News Feed</h3>
                        <Posts className="pull-left col-lg-10" postimgsrc="http://tedxtargumures.com/wp-content/themes/TEDxTheme-develop/images/defaults/video-placeholder.jpg" imgsrc="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/7/70/Shawn_Tok_Profile.jpg" name="Hakeem" textcontent="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus placerat tellus ac magna imperdiet, ut gravida orci commodo. Curabitur sagittis dui velit, vel vehicula erat aliquet sed. Vestibulum pharetra tortor in velit iaculis placerat. Vestibulum sed rutrum tortor. Vivamus finibus libero nisl, nec fermentum justo vestibulum a. Morbi sed ante ullamcorper, luctus nulla nec, convallis justo. Etiam tortor metus, porttitor eu fringilla nec, tempor ut mauris. Donec lacinia arcu at tellus sollicitudin, vel dictum eros vulputate. Nam eu arcu ut purus volutpat condimentum quis vel arcu."/>
                      </div>
                      <Rightbar />
                    </main>
                </aside>
            </div>
        );
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("page"));
```

header.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import Router from 'react-router';
import { DefaultRoute, Link, Route, RouteHandler } from 'react-router';

let navigationActionCreators = require('../actions/navigation-action-creators.jsx');
let header = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return{typed: ''};
    },
    //Event that gets fired when user enters text
    handleChange: function(event) {
        this.setState({typed: event.target.value});

        //Search page to be rendered
        var SearchPage = React.createClass({

            render: function() {
                return <div>You typed:{this.state.typed}</div>
            }

        });

        //Render search page in real time as user enters input
        ReactDOM.render(<p>You searched for<h3>{this.state.typed}</h3></p>, document.getElementById("main-container"));
    },

    //Event that gets fired when navigation item is clicked
    handleClick: function() {
        navigationActionCreators.navigateTo({
            component:componentname
        });
        var Page = React.createClass({
            render: function() {
                return (
                    <div>
                        Page
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
        ReactDOM.render(<Page/>, document.getElementById("main-container"));
    },
    render:function() {
        return (
            <div className="col-lg-12">
                <li className='pull-left'><Link to "app">Home</Link></a></li>
                <li className="pull-left"><a onClick={this.handleClick}>Notifications</a></li>
                <li className="pull-left"><a onClick={this.handleClick}>Find friends</a></li>
                <input id="site-search" type="text" onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.setState.typed} placeholder="search..." aria-label="..." className="col-lg-2 pull-right"/>
                <RouteHandler/>
            </div>
        );
    }

});

let routes = (
    <Route name="app" path="/" handler={App}>
        <Route name="login" path="/login" handler={LoginHandler}/>
    </Route>
)

Router.run(routes, function(Handler){
    React.render(<Handler/>, document.body);
});

module.exports = header;
```

My package.json looks like this...

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.13.2",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.5",
    "debug": "~2.2.0",
    "express": "~4.13.1",
    "jade": "~1.11.0",
    "morgan": "~1.6.1",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "alt": "^0.18.1",
    "babel-core": "^6.3.21",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "^1.1.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.3.13",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "flux": "^2.1.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-transform-hmr": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9",
    "webpack-livereload-plugin": "^0.4.0"
  }
}
```

I've been battling this bug for the last 24 hours and had no luck. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Use double quotes instead of single quotes. As you can see, the arrow points to the quote. Also, `<Link to "app">Home</Link>` looks invalid. Seems you are missing a `=`.

Comment: Omg. Thanks so much. At this point I'm not sure if I should be happy or mad at myself since I literally stared at this for a day and still didn't notice that. It's always the simple things that get me.

Comment: Use a linter to detect these problems early!

Comment: why you have an `</a>` after the `<link>` tag?

Comment: @FelixKling Can you move that as an answer so we can get this question closed?